# Почему изменяется массив, передающийся в функцию через .copy()

Tags: python

Пишу алгоритм для работы с двумерным списком, и почему-то изначальный массив, который я передаю в функцию через `.copy()` изменяется, хотя функция не обращается к нему. Может, там, конечно, какая-то глупая ошибка, но я как-то не могу её найти.

[image: Код программы]

[image: Вывод]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-copy.html

может `deepcopy` использовать?

все таки у вас список списков, а не список обычных чисел

Comment: То есть, изменяется ссылка на массив, но ссылки на массивы внутри него остаются теми же, правильно?

Comment: Я проверил, теперь всё работает правильно, благодарю!